# Are there any plugin or code to add placeholder template for TinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-plugins

I have content with placeholder such as `[[name]]`, `[[lastname]]`.
I want everything from `[[` until `]]` gets highlight, for example in yellow background while the real content that will be save in DB is still plain text.

For easier to understand, please take a look at this link. https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/features/placeholder.html
It is placeholder plugin for **CKEditor**. And here is working sample. https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/placeholder.html

Currently I use **textpattern** plugin for TinyMCE and this code.

```
tinymce.init({
    // options...
    'textpattern_patterns': [
        {'start': '[[', 'end': ']]', 'cmd': 'KPHW'}
    ],
    'setup': function(editor) {
        editor.addCommand('KPHW', function(ui, v) {
            let contentText = editor.selection.getContent({ format: 'text' });
            editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<span style="background-color: yellow;">[[' + contentText + ']]</span>');
        });
    }
});
```

But it replace plain text `[[placeholder]]` with `<span style="background: yellow;">[[placeholder]]</span>` which is wrong.

Comment: This comment helped me out big time, it's unrelated and I don't have an answer, but I couldn't find a straightforward way to add a custom command on TinyMCE and this helped me out, thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found this variable plugin https://github.com/ziktar/tinymce-variable.

Still have some bugs but is most active.